# Using WebGrease.config with bundling in ASP.Net project

Tags: asp.net, css, bundle, webgrease

I'm trying to work on with new features in bundle that's using `WebGrease.config` file and unfortunately its not working like `Bundle.Config` file and i can't use its output virtual name.
I learned from this site (http://webgrease.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Example%20WebGrease%20configuration%20file) also this one (http://kenhaines.net/post/2012/06/25/How-to-use-Webgrease-Configuration-Files.aspx) after all I can't run css files with this WebGrease.Config file like old way with Bundle.Config file.

```
<Settings>
  <ImageDirectories>IMG</ImageDirectories>
  <ImageExtensions>*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.ico</ImageExtensions>
</Settings>

<CssFileSet name="SampleCss" output="Style/css">
  <Autoname>
    <RenameFiles>true</RenameFiles>
  </Autoname>

  <Spriting config="Release">
    <SpriteImages>true</SpriteImages>
    <AutoVersionBackgroundImages>true</AutoVersionBackgroundImages>
  </Spriting>


  <Inputs>
    <Input>TestStyle.css</Input>
  </Inputs>
</CssFileSet>
```

Is there is something wrong with my file or is there is a way to call output link from my project.

Any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks.